# INKSCAPE//Is there ANY way to split a path in 2 paths or does it just not work?

Tags: inkscape, path

INKSCAPE// 
It also needs to be separated on a 'outline'level...

You can put nodes on top of each other so it seems that is really is split up in a normal view but it is not...

Thanks,

Sabrina

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what you have, what you want to achieve, and where you fail. Ideally provide some screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, add a node by double clicking using the Edit Paths by Nodes Tool (F2), where you want the split, or alternatively select a node, and hit the "Break Path at Selected Nodes" icon in the toolbar.

[image]

After doing this, the paths will still be combined, but you can fix that. Click *Path > Break Apart*, to separate the paths entirely.